# android admob ads are not showing (it depends on keystore file???)

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have very weird case so please read it fully to understand. My android app was signed with keystore file before and I tried to add apk on appstore but my admob ads never worked. My testAdd works perfectly, but at the moment I change test add with real add, the add never shows because it never loads it.
Few days ago in one of my desperate tries I decided to sign my app with different keystore (don't ask me why I really run out of ideas). And BAAAAMM my ads started working normaly!!!

I was thrilled at the beginning till the moment I realized I can not upload apk with different keystore file :(

Please does anyone have any idea what is connection between new keystore and admobs and FIRSTLY why real ads never work with my first keystore file